# angular/fire get next item in collection using startAfter

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I am having trouble getting the next item in a collection using [angular/fire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/fire).

The error I am getting is:

> Error: Function startAfter() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: a custom AngularFirestoreDocument object

Based on [these Firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/query-cursors#use_a_document_snapshot_to_define_the_query_cursor) I think `startAfter()` wants a DocumentSnapshot but I don't know how to convert `AngularFirestoreDocument` to `DocumentSnapshot` and whilst [the angular/fire docs](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/querying-collections.md#4-querying-collections-in-angularfirestore) mention `startAfter` they do not give any code examples.

Here's my problem code. I want the first document in the collection after the `video` document.

```
getNextVideo$(id: string, group: string): Observable<IVideo> {

  const video: AngularFirestoreDocument<IVideo> = this.afs.doc<IVideo>(`videos/${id}`)

  const collection: AngularFirestoreCollection<IVideo> = this.afs.collection<IVideo>('videos', ref => {
    return ref
      .where('group', '==', group)
      .where('flowPlayerProcessed', '==', true)
      .orderBy('timeCreated')
      .startAfter(video) // <<<<< ERROR IS HERE
      .limit(1)
  })

  return collection.valueChanges().pipe(
    map((videos: IVideo[]) => videos.length ? videos[0] : null)
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK this rather verbose monstrosity works

```
getNextVideo$(id: string, group: string): Observable<IVideo> {

  const video: AngularFirestoreDocument<IVideo> = this.afs.doc<IVideo>(`videos/${id}`)

  return video.snapshotChanges().pipe(
    switchMap((videoSnapshotAction: Action<DocumentSnapshot<IVideo>>) => {

      const videoSnapshot: DocumentSnapshot<IVideo> = videoSnapshotAction.payload

      const collection: AngularFirestoreCollection<IVideo> = this.afs.collection<IVideo>('videos', ref => {
        return ref
          .where('group', '==', group)
          .where('flowPlayerProcessed', '==', true)
          .orderBy('timeCreated')
          .startAfter(videoSnapshot)
          .limit(1)
      })
      return collection.valueChanges().pipe(
        map((videos: IVideo[]) => videos.length ? videos[0] : null)
      )
    })
  )
}
```